# Add a decimal to a string

Tags: javascript, string, decimal-point

I have a script that takes a big number and counts up.  The script converts the number to a string so that it can be formatted with commas, but I also need to add a decimal place before the last two digits.  I know that this line handles the commas:

```
if ((i+1) % 3 == 0 && (amount.length-1) !== i)output = ',' + output;
```

Is there a similar line of code I can add that accomplishes adding a decimal point?

Comment: Are you sure that line works? Looks wrong to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you always want the decimal before the last two:

```
function numberIt(str) {
    //number before the decimal point
    num = str.substring(0,str.length-3);
    //number after the decimal point
    dec = str.substring(str.length-2,str.length-1)
    //connect both parts while comma-ing the first half
    output = commaFunc(num) + "." + dec;

    return output;
}
```

When `commaFunc()` is the function you described that adds commas.

**EDIT**

After much hard work, the full correct code:

http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/TT8BH/21/

Comment: this looks like the solution to me.  I've plugged your script into my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/blackessej/TT8BH/12/ and renamed the function that adds the commas, but I'm not terribly good at javascript yet and it's not working for me.  Any pointers?

Comment: it doesn't output when run...how are we adding the function to the output in your example?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to just add a line below my comma seperating line that adds the decimal in the one place, before the last two digits...

Comment: okay so what ou want to do is break it into the two parts as I have shown you above (num, dec) and only put num through the beginning of your of your function and add the two parts after with the seperating period after. As done here: http://jsfiddle.net/TT8BH/14/

Comment: Again, it's not outputting the number when I hit run. Also, I'm concerned that this won't generate the output that I need.  I need the decimal amount to count up, as well, so I would have to run the whole number through the count function.  You'll have to forgive me because I don't know how to write js very well...I hope that my code is at least somewhat easy to work with...

Comment: Ok, After much hard work here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/TT8BH/19/
I finally got what you were trying to do... I've also corrected another mistake of yours where you used `++counter`, Javascript doesn't support this.

Comment: here is the script, functioning with commas but without the decimal place, as it works right now: http://jsfiddle.net/blackessej/TT8BH/20/.  I simply want to add the decimal before the last two digits in the output, keeping the commas in the appropriate place.

Comment: Nm last comment.  You had commented out `intervalId=setInterval(f,interval);`, now it's working perfectly.  Thank you @nayish!

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure want the decimal to be just before the last two digits? That way `1234` would become `12.34` and not `1234.00`, I'm assuming you want the second one, in that case you should use JavaScript's built in method .toFixed()

**Note** I didn't write the format_number function, I took it from the website below and modified it a bit.

http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic2.html

http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html

```
// example 1
var num = 10;
var output = num.toFixed(2); // output = 10.00

// example 2, if you want commas aswell
function format_number(nStr)
{
    nStr = nStr.toFixed(2);
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}

var num = 1234;
var output = format_number(num); // output = 1,234.00
```